# Working in a field.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, finite-fields

When I calculate vector spaces, diagonalization of matrices, linear transformations on a field, can I work in $\mathbb R$ and ultimately transform the result to that field?

For example if I calculate the basis of a subspace in $\mathbb Z_5$, can I calculate in $\mathbb R$ and when I finish I transform to $\mathbb Z_5$?

Comment: No, since in $\Bbb R$ you can invert $5$, but in $\Bbb Z_5$ you cannot, say. In $\Bbb R$, for example $5\neq 0$; but $5=0$ in $\Bbb Z_5$. As an example, consider the family of groups ${\rm PSL}(n,q)$. These groups are all simple except in the cases $(2,2)$ and $(2,3)$, and this happens precisely because the matrix algebra in $\Bbb F_2$ and $\Bbb F_3$ is quite particular in the $2\times 2$ case.

Comment: It's anyway not clear what precisely is meant by "work in $R$ and transform the result to that field."

Comment: I mean for example: give me an matrix with elements in $\Bbb Z_5$, and ask me if diagonalizable try and calculate the diagonal matrix.
My question is, can I do the calculation in $\Bbb R$ and finally when you already have the results transform elements $\Bbb Z_5$

Comment: Provided you are using only properties common to all fields. Division by a sum may not be valid, Anything involving linear order, or limits,, or existence of roots of a polynomial, are not common properties.

Comment: $\Bbb{R}$ is problematic for many a reason. $\Bbb{Q}$ and its finite extensions are better. If your structure is defined over a number field, it often suffices to work over its ring of integers. That ring has prime ideals lying above $5$, and with a little bit of luck you can reduce things modulo such an ideal in the end, ending up with the field $\Bbb{F}_5$ or its finite extension. The process is available in e.g. elliptic curves (good reduction) and representation theory. But it does not work always for e.g. the reasons in Pedro's comment.